# Transport rules on a live@edu instance to filter SSNs

Tags: windows

Has anyone implemented transport rules on a live@edu(or whatever Microsoft is calling it these days) instance to reject the delivery of messages that include SSN's? I see how to set up transport rules in Exchange 2007, and even how to do it in the Windows Live Admin page, though the rules there don't seem to allow for regexes, can anyone confirm this? If this is the case has anyone ever connected Powershell to a live@edu instance to implement the code found at the bottom of this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997187.aspx
What I really need is a concise how-to.

Comment: Just curious, what pattern do you use in Exchange. Something like 
'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]' or something actually the filters for 'real' SSN's. I know there are blocks SSN's that don't get issued.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the commandlet 'Set-TransportRule' is not one of the ones that Outlook Live's [remote powershell supports](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/dd575549.aspx), I consider it very unlikely that any transport rules can be set at all. We're using this service, and I don't see anything that suggests its possible.

Comment: sadly that help.outlook.com article is out of date.  I'm not sure if it was R4 that added more commands or if it's just been a while since they ginned up fresh doco.

Answer (score 0):

outlook live doesn't currently offer that level of control over the service.  You can only set transport rules and supervision rules on specific words, not patterns

Answer (score 0):

http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ms.exch.ecp.learnmoretransportrules.aspx
suggests that you can use powershell to make more complex rules than what are provided in the web management interface, which is where you can use supervision rules to only search for specific words instead of patterns. the list of cmdlets Outlook Live supports is also a "quick" list, so i'm assuming that means it isn't complete. only on way to find out though...